# Weighted Average rating through mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to do a query to sort by "weighted average"

There is 5 values from 1-5 possible. Weighted average is

(n5*5 + n4*4 + n3*3 + n2*2 + n1*1) / (n5+n4+n3+n2+n1)

Where n5 would be the count of objects with rating: 5

I have the following example. If you find better structure to store I am happy to hear.

```
{
    "_id" : "wPg4jzJsEFXNxR5Wf",
    "caveId" : "56424a93819e7419112c883e",
    "data" : [
        {
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "value" : 3
        },
        {
            "value" : 4
        },
        {
            "value" : 2
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "oSrtv33MgnkJFvNan",
    "caveId" : "56424a93819e7419112c949f",
    "data" : [
        {
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "value" : 4
        },
        {
            "value" : 4
        },
        {
            "value" : 2
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "gJRMMQPwDwjFrL7zz",
    "caveId" : "56424a93819e7419112c8727",
    "data" : [
        {
            "value" : 5
        },
        {
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "value" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Example of _ID: oSrtv33MgnkJFvNan (Second one)

(2*4 + 1*2 + 1*1)/(2+1+1) = 2.75

Then I would want to sort all the documents by that value.

Order would be

1. gJRMMQPwDwjFrL7zz: value: 3.33
2. oSrtv33MgnkJFvNan: value 2.75
3. wPg4jzJsEFXNxR5Wf: value 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer is really both "yes" and "no" in respect to can MongoDB sort data from calculation like this. It can of course do it, but possibly not in a practical way for your purpose.

The two tools MongoDB has to do any sort of calculation are the a[ggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/). The former currently lacks the operators to really handle this in a practical way. The second can be "tricked" into sorting, as an artifact of how mapReduce works, by putting the component to be sorted in the grouping key (even if there is no actual grouping).

So you can basically apply the math with something like this:

```js
db.data.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var vals = this.data.map(function(el){ return el.value }),
            uniq = {};

        vals.forEach(function(el) {
            if (!uniq.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
                uniq[el] = 1;
            } else {
                uniq[el]++;
            }
        });

        var weight = Array.sum(Object.keys(uniq).map(function(key) {
            return uniq[key] * key
        })) / Array.sum(Object.keys(uniq).map(function(key) {
            return uniq[key];
        }))

        var id = this._id;
        delete this._id;

        emit({ "weight": weight, "orig": id },this);

    },
    function() {},
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Which gives you this output:

```js
{
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "weight" : 2.5,
                            "orig" : "wPg4jzJsEFXNxR5Wf"
                    },
                    "value" : {
                            "caveId" : "56424a93819e7419112c883e",
                            "data" : [
                                    {
                                            "value" : 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "value" : 3
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "value" : 4
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "value" : 2
                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "weight" : 2.75,
                            "orig" : "oSrtv33MgnkJFvNan"
                    },
                    "value" : {
                            "caveId" : "56424a93819e7419112c949f",
                            "data" : [
                                    {
                                            "value" : 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "value" : 4
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "value" : 4
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "value" : 2
                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "weight" : 3.3333333333333335,
                            "orig" : "gJRMMQPwDwjFrL7zz"
                    },
                    "value" : {
                            "caveId" : "56424a93819e7419112c8727",
                            "data" : [
                                    {
                                            "value" : 5
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "value" : 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "value" : 4
                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            }
    ]
}
```

So all the results are sorted, but of course the restriction applies that mapReduce can only produce "inline" output that is under the 16MB BSON limit, or alternately write the results out to another collection.

Even with new features being added to the aggregation framework that can assist here ( from current development series 3.1.x ) this would still require some juggling with `$unwind` in order to get the "sum" of elements in any way ( no such feature as a "reduce" function yet ), which does not make it a stable or practical alternative.

So you can do it with mapReduce, but for my money I would have another process that calculates this to run periodicallly ( or triggered on updates ) and update a standard "weight" field on the document, that could then be used directly for sorting.

Having a value in place in your documents is always the most performant option.

---

For the curious, you can grab a development branch release of MongoDB ( 3.1.x series ), or any release after that and apply an aggregation pipeline like this:

```js
db.data.aggregate([
    {  "$project": {
        "caveId": 1,
        "data": 1,
        "conv": {
            "$setUnion": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$data",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": "$$el.value"
                }},
                []
            ]
        },
        "orig": { 
            "$map": {
                "input": "$data",
                "as": "el",
                "in": "$$el.value"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "caveId": 1,
        "data": 1,
        "conv": 1,
        "orig": 1,
        "counts": { "$map": {
            "input": "$conv",
            "as": "el",
            "in": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$orig",
                        "as": "o",
                        "cond": { 
                            "$eq": [ "$$o", "$$el" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
    }},
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$conv", "includeArrayIndex": true } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "caveId": { "$first": "$caveId" },
        "data": { "$first": "$data" },
        "counts": { "$first": "$counts" },
        "mult": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$multiply": [ 
                    "$conv.value", 
                    { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$counts", "$conv.index" ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$counts" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "caveId": { "$first": "$caveId" },
        "data": { "$first": "$data" },
        "count": { "$sum": "$counts" },
        "mult": { "$first": "$mult" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "data": 1,
        "weight": { "$divide": [ "$mult", "$count" ] }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "weight": 1 } }
])
```

But even with helpers like `$filter` and "includeArrayIndex" in `$unwind` and the `$arrayElemAt` operator using that index later to match up the distinct elements with their counts, the usage of `$unwind` in any way makes this a non-performant solution.

It may become practical in the future if operators like `$map` can produce index values needed for pairing and with the introduction of any methods to similarly do an "in-line sum" operation or other math on array results without processing `$unwind`. But as of writing this does not exist, even in development.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive writeup! I doubt I am going to have lots of ratings but maybe it would be wise to have a cronjob that does the calculations. I will try them both and look at some performance metrics.

Comment: @Chris That is a wise choice. I have a common mantra of "test,test and then test again". Which largely refers to performance characteristics of code and approaches and finding out which best suits the situation. You can always calculate "on the fly" if it turns out to be the most efficient. But really the choice should always be the one that is the most efficient.